# <input type=“text” maxlength=“4”> should not count comma and dot in maxlength

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript

I have input field which contains number and special characters e.g. comma and dot
while calulating the maxLength of the field i want to skip special characters .

I dont want to restrict the special character.

**Expected Output should be :- 1,234 (Total Length :- 4)**

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
       Username: <input type="text" maxlength="3" id="myId"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

jsfiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rushijogle/8vwd0xzm/2/)

Comment: u need to restrict the comma right?

Comment: No, I dont want to restrict the comma. I want when i entered the comma then maxlength should not calculate comma into the length

Comment: Use Javascript to increase the value of the maxlength attribute when a comma is entered. Anyway, if you really want to allow 1234 as an input value, maxlength=3 isn't enough.

Comment: `maxlength` counts _everything_ regardless of what you want, the only way around that is to use javascript to handle keys yourself as Artūrs and yellie suggest, or fiddle with maxlength as Mr Lister says. You could use HTML5 validation but that will only flag incorrect entries, not prevent them.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this javascript:

```
 window.onload = function() {

    var textInput = document.getElementById("myId");

    textInput.oninput = function() {
      var temp;
      temp = this.value.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi,'');
      if (temp.length > 3) {
        alert("Invalid"); // Or other stuff you want to do
      }
    };
  };
```

Note that this code checks input on real time

Answer (score 0):

This should be done with javascript:

```
var input = document.getElementById('myId');

input.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
  // Checking length of string ignoring all non-digit and non-letter characters
  if (this.value.replace(/[^\d|[^a-zA-Z]]*/g, '').length == 3) { 
    console.log('stop and do whatever you need')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use HTML5 `pattern` attribute. Just instead of `maxlength` type `pattern` and give it some regex. Could do something like this:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
       Username: <input type="text" pattern="(?(?=^.\d{1,3},\d{1,3}$)^.{5}$|^.{4}$)" id="myId"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: This pattern does not work? Can you check out https://jsfiddle.net/pgwsqm4f/ Pattern attribute value (?(?=^.\d{1,3},\d{1,3}$)^.{5}$|^.{4}$) is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?(?=^.\d{1,3},\d{1,3}$)^.{5}$|^.{4}$)/: Invalid group